# Marathon backoff - is it really exponential?

Tags: marathon

I'm trying to figure out Marathon's exponential backoff configuration. Here's the documentation:

> The backoffSeconds and backoffFactor values are multiplied until they reach the maxLaunchDelaySeconds value. After they reach that value, Marathon waits maxLaunchDelaySeconds before repeating this cycle exponentially. For example, if backoffSeconds: 3, backoffFactor: 2, and maxLaunchDelaySeconds: 3600, there will be ten attempts to launch a failed task, each three seconds apart. After these ten attempts, Marathon will wait 3600 seconds before repeating this cycle.

The way I think of exponential backoff is that the wait periods should be:

3*2^0 = 3

3*2^1 = 6

3*2^2 = 12

3*2^3 = 24 and so on

so every time the app crashes, Marathon will wait a longer period of time before retrying. However, given the description above, Marathon's logic for waiting looks something like this:

```
int retryCount = 0;
while(backoffSeconds * (backoffFactor ^ retryCount) < maxLaunchDelaySeconds)
{
   wait(backoffSeconds);
   retryCount++;
}
wait(maxLaunchDelaySeconds);
```

This matches the explanation in the documentation, since 3*2^x < 3600 for values of x fewer than or equal to 10. However, I really don't see how it can be called an exponential backoff, since the wait time is constant.

Is there a way to make Marathon wait progressively longer times with every restart of the app? Am I misunderstand the doc? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand the code in the RateLimiter.scala, it is like you described, but then capped to the maxLaunchDelay waiting period. Let`s say maxLaunchDelay is one hour (3600s)

1. 3*2^0 = 3
2. 3*2^1 = 6
3. 3*2^2 = 12
4. 3*2^3 = 24
5. 3*2^4 = 48
6. 3*2^5 = 96
7. 3*2^6 = 192
8. 3*2^7 = 384
9. 3*2^8 = 768
10. 3*2^9 = 1536
11. 3*2^10 = 3072
12. 3*2^11 = 3600 (6144)
13. 3*2^12 = 3600 (12288)
14. 3*2^13 = 3600 (24576)

Which brings us a typically 2^n graph, see [image: graph]

You would get a bigger increase, if you would other backoffFactors,

for example backoff factor 10:
[image: backoff factor 10]

or backoff factor 20:
[image: backoff factor 20]

Additionally I saw a re-work of this topic, code review currently open here: https://phabricator.mesosphere.com/D1007

What do you think?

Thanks
Johannes